# ORACLE - 03113: end of file on communication channel for specific query

Tags: .net, database, oracle

Calling all Oracle heads, I've got a weird problem with a sql query...

Running locally, an IIS server running a basic web service executing a query via a VPN connection to another Oracle database.

Many other queries work, some more that take longer to return data.

It's an Oracle 9i database.

Initially I was using an Oracle 11g client, then switched back to 10g thinking it may be that.

I thought it may be a ADO.NET Oracle driver issue, so extracted the sql to a file a ran it directly from sqlplus (console).  Same thing.  01331 after about 1 second.

I can run the same query on the target site using an old 4gl sql editor using 9i client and it works.  I tested it on SQL Worksheet on the client at the target site it work.

The only thing unusual with this sql statement is that it performs a tree walk using the CONNECT BY function.

I don't think it's a time out issue as more complex (well certainly larger) queries eventually return data.  I did something like select count(*) from largetable where longstring not like '%test%' to provide enough time to try an recreate a timeout, but it didn't.  Additionally the 03113 error occurs quite quickly after executing the statement.  Nothing I can see in the sqlnet.log.

I would really appreciate any pointers?

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: You need help from your DBA to see what is going on on server side when you run this "specific" query.

Comment: To ring bearer's point, an ORA-03113 error frequently indicates that the session on the database failed for some reason.  If that happened, a trace file should be generated on the database server (it may be written to the alert log as well).  Can you ask the DBA whether something was written to the alert log at the time the error was raised and ask for any trace files related to that failure?

Comment: I'm getting the alert log back to look at it, but believe it is environmental, as the same query does work on the other network - albeit using a different client version.  I'll see what they say and let you know.

Comment: ok, started getting the error again.  this time running the query over connection via VPN. the same query runs perfectly well on the other side of the connection, other queries work ok.  is this a time out issue?  using 11.2 client and ODP.NET. Is there a sqlnet timeout for long running queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem to be including a column of type long in the select query.

Can anybody think of a reason for this?

Tried two Oracle clients (10/11) over two guest os' (Vista/Windows 7) and same problem.
Different local firewalls, no Oracle alert logs, no sqlnet logs. No idea.

Any further suggestions? Or is it Oracle support time?

---

I managed to solve this problem.  I ended up porting the .net project to .net 4 and using the Oracle.DataAccess provider.

The original query contained a nested treewalk using the connect by function, which worked on the server, but not from the client.  I kept getting ORA03113.

I had further problems using the 2.x version of the ODP.NET - ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error.  To solve this I installed the latest oracle client, 11.2 and the latest ODP.NET client, 11.2.  Granted permissions to oracle home (and sub folders/item) - rebooted.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: after this I'm once again experiencing the 3113 error. see comment on original question.

Answer (score 0):

This normally indicates a bug in the query optimization engine.  I ran into some issues with this very thing with 9i and most recently 11g.

Here are your options

```
1)  ReWrite the query (check for joins to views, etc) and try to restructure it
2)  Work with Oracle support
```

I can tell you the issue I discovered with 9i Oracle refused to acknowledge / fix.  :)

Answer (score 0):

On one of the databases(v 12.2), I got this error when calling a procedure to which I have no rights from another procedure to which I have rights. maybe it will help someone